# Renaming files using part of the path name

Tags: bash, find, rename

I need to rename all logs using part of the directory name.

The logs appear like so:

```
friday13/stack123/FooBar-QA-123/000001.gz
friday13/stack123/FooBar-QA-123/000002.gz
friday13/stack123/FooBar-QA-123/000003.gz

friday13/stack123/FooBar-Stage-456/000001.gz
friday13/stack123/FooBar-Stage-456/000002.gz
friday13/stack123/FooBar-Stage-456/000003.gz

friday13/stack123/FooBar-Prod-789/000001.gz
friday13/stack123/FooBar-Prod-789/000002.gz
friday13/stack123/FooBar-Prod-789/000003.gz
```

For each of the files in the above directories, I need to rename them as such:

```
FooBar-QA-123-000001.gz
FooBar-QA-123-000002.gz
FooBar-QA-123-000003.gz

FooBar-Stage-456-000001.gz
FooBar-Stage-456-000002.gz
FooBar-Stage-456-000003.gz

FooBar-Prod-789-000001.gz
FooBar-Prod-789-000002.gz
FooBar-Prod-789-000003.gz
```

Help is greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: You have chosen appropriate tags. Can you share your attempts at solving the problem?

Comment: With quite a few directories to sift through, and filenames to rename, I had thought to start out my command with a "find friday13 -type -f" in order to focus on the logfile itself.  However, it's not clear to me how or whether to assign variables to each of the folders leading up to the file.

With this example:  friday13/stack123/FooBar-QA-123/000001.gz

friday13 = $1
stack123 = $2
FooBar-QA-123 = $3

and rename as such "mv 000001.gz  $1-$2-$3-1.gz.  (preserving the 6th character in the filename)

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter expansion for [substring removal](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal), in order to create
the target argument for the `mv` command for each filename that `find` returns:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%/*}-${1##*/}"' sh {} \;
```

Or the same using `dirname` and `basename`:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c '
    mv -- "$1" "$(dirname "$1")-$(basename "$1")"
' sh {} \;
```

Note: Always, first replace `mv` with `echo` to test any similar command.

Comment: this works well, and I can use as-is.  Two things though.  1)  the file gets moved into the previous directory, as opposed to remaining in the current directory.  2)  the file name doesn't preserve the 6th character in the filename.    Again, I can live without these things.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently thanasisp's answer is based on your post and the example output you provided, but does not change `/` into `-`.  In order to get the full processing that you seem to expect in your adjoined comment (beneath your post) here is what could do to preserve you files' basenames from the 6th character on...

Provided the detection of files of interest is good with:

```
$ find friday13 -type f -name "*.gz"
```

(you need to confirm that that basic `find` cmd above performs well for you), then the complete cmd becomes:

```
$ find friday13 -type f -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c '
      var=$(sed "s/\//-/g;s/^\.-//" < <(echo $1));
      echo mv -- "$1" "${var%-*}-$(cut -c6- < <(echo ${var##*-}))"
      ' execbash {} \;
```

and just erase the `echo` in the snippet above once you are satisfied that the printed `mv` cmds fit your bill.